# ¿Cómo sacar la diferencia en horas de dos fechas en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datetime, date

Hola lo que sucede es que necesito sacar la diferencia entre dos datos por ejemplo:

```
String fecha_entra ="2018/09/13 10:14:00"

String fecha_sale ="2018/09/14 01:10:20"
```

Y en una tercera variable el resultado en horas. Sé que esos datos van con formatos, pero no he podido dar con el código correcto, agradezco de antemano su colaboración.

Comment: Te dejo un enlace a SO en inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285161/android-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día Juan te comparto una manera en la que puedes obtener la diferencia en horas:

```
try {
    //Lo primero que tienes que hacer es establecer el formato que tiene tu fecha para que puedas obtener un objeto de tipo Date el cual es el que se utiliza para obtener la diferencia.
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());

    //Parceas tus fechas en string a variables de tipo date se agrega un try catch porque si el formato declarado anteriormente no es igual a tu fecha obtendrás una excepción
    Date dateStart = dateFormat.parse("2018/09/13 10:14:00");
    Date dateEnd = dateFormat.parse("2018/09/14 01:10:20");

    //obtienes la diferencia de las fechas
    long difference = Math.abs(dateEnd.getTime() - dateStart.getTime());

    //obtienes la diferencia en horas ya que la diferencia anterior esta en milisegundos
    difference= difference / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    Log.e("Difference: " ,  Long.toString(difference));

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad mi aporte saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este código, te dejo un ejemplo funcionando sobre un Main.
Primero obtienes la diferencia en milisegundos, posteriormente conviertes los milisegundos a horas con la clase TimeUnit.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long total = new Date("2018/09/14 01:10:20").getTime() - new Date("2018/09/13 10:14:00").getTime();
    long horas = TimeUnit.HOURS.convert(total, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("Diferencia en horas: " + horas);
  }
}
```

[Aquí](https://repl.it/repls/MammothGrumpyCurrencies) el ejemplo funcionando.